# Retrofit 2 not giving response

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2.0
API: https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?
API interface:

```
public interface NewsAPI {
    // source : the-next-web
    // SortBy : latest
    @GET("/articles")
    Call<Article> articles(
            @Query("source") String source,
            @Query("apiKey") String apiKey);
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class ArticlesFragment extends Fragment {

    private NewsAPI newsAPI;

    public ArticlesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_list, container, false);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(" https://newsapi.org/v1/")
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        newsAPI = retrofit.create(NewsAPI.class);
        loadArticle();
        return rootView;
    }

    public void loadArticle() {
        Call<Article> call =
                newsAPI.articles("the-next-web", "apiKey");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Article>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Article> call, Response<Article> response) {

                final Article article = response.body();
                if (article != null) {
                    Log.v("this", "YES! response");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Article> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.v("this", "NO response ");

            }
        });
    }
```

## Update

Use interceptor v3.4.1 otherwise you will get following error- java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method log(Ljava/lang/String;)V in class Lokhttp3/internal/Platform; or its super classes

Configuration for 2.1.0 looks like this:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
```

Comment: Either `onResponse` or `onFailure` must be called. Does the app crash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the space in  `.baseUrl(" https://newsapi.org/v1/")`.
This could be the problem.

## Update

Implement `HttpLoggingInterceptor`. This way you'll see the `GET` you're making. Here is a little help with code.

```
public static OkHttpClient GetClient(){
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        return  httpClient.addInterceptor(logging).build();
        }
```

And in retrofit will be like this...

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(GetClient())
                .baseUrl("https://newsapi.org/v1/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

Comment: I want to show this Json data in list view
I have my custom Array Adapter
What should I do?

Comment: @OmerDanish Okay, nice to hear that...
Tell me now...
`final Article article = response.body();` In this you are getting just an object or a list of articles?

The basic code would be...

`CustomListAdapter customAdapter = new CustomListAdapter (this, R.layout.your_custom_item_row, yourListView );

yourListView .setAdapter(customAdapter);`

Comment: FiN thankyou I have got it working
List<Article_> result = article.getArticles();
                    mAdapter.clear();
                    mAdapter.addAll(result);

Comment: @OmerDanish if you think my answer was helpful, please mark it as answer, so it can help other members of s.o.

Comment: @OmerDanish replace with this...
`compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'`

Answer (score 1):

Remove slash from `@GET("/articles")`. This makes your final url `https://newsapi.org/v1//articles`. Since you've used `https://newsapi.org/v1/` to build your retrofit.